# Resize Android Webview according to defined size

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have tried to set the size for `Webview` that I define in program. But, when I run the app, the `Webview` is displayed fit to device screen. I don't want this to happen. How can I have my own size of Webview? Anyone can help?

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.setPadding(50,0,0,50);
wv.setInitialScale(getScale());
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I have created the screen size in this method:

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(PIC_WIDTH);
    val = val * 71d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

How to make the WebView to be displayed according to the size that I want?

Comment: add the WebView in a layout & set its height, width as you need.?

Comment: @DarShan yes, I've added the WebView in a new layout & set its width and height that I want. It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Below Code To set the height of webview.

In your layout file, for e.g.: `webview.xml`

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width=“100dp”
    android:layout_height=“200dp”/>
```

then in your Activity,

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```